# When is it OK to position content outside the .container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen some Bootstrap web pages where elements (such as toolbar) are positioned outside of the .container. Is it a good practice, or is it discouraged? What are the guidelines as to what should and should not live inside a container?

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap is is normal position the toolbar / navbar outside the `.container`, so for the `header` or `footer` every of this element have a proper `.container`.  Container is for main information. All the accessory element al normally out of this  class.

Comment: Can header, footer and sidebar live in containers of their own? I've seen a sidebar design that is in its own container-fluid

Comment: Yes is tipical, Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house the  grid system. you can use separate container for HTML5 semantics areas

Comment: So, what does a container do and why can't I just put a bunch of rows everywhere?

Comment: For Bootstrap 3 `.container` is for fluid and and especially in the most appropriate way to handle the grid of 12 columns that enables a provision of the controlled content. The fact that you are using rows and columns and act according to your needs depends on the result you want to achieve.